# Update existing object with new values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering how you could update an existing object with new values. I have a simple account object with the following properties

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Forename {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
    public DateTime RegisterDate {get; set;}
    public string Occupation {get; set;}
}
```

In my project I have a simple edit method which allows a user to update their Forename, Surname and Occupation.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Account editFormDetails)
{
    var accountDetails = GetAccountDetails(account.Id) //Gets a users existing details from db

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is there a nice way of updating the existing object(accountDetails) with the new values from the editFromDetails object? I would do clone, however, the fields in my edit form can be left empty, so I may not need to update. I've simplified my object in this example to make it less verbose. Any help would be great.

Comment: Try ValueInjecter: https://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/

Comment: There are several libraries that have solved this problem for you. ValueInjector, AutoMapper, and so on. However I think you will find that having the edit form post a null for values that they did not want to edit is going to lead to some issues.

Answer (score 5):

Use NuGet to install a library called `AutoMapper`

> PM> Install-Package AutoMapper

Once installed, you will need to create maps between each Type that you wish to update, if the properties of the types match (like in the example I've given below), then the library will automatically be able to map those properties to each other...

```
void Main()
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ChangeNameViewModel, User>()
        .ForMember(member => member.FirstName, viewModel => viewModel.Condition(source => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.FirstName)))
        .ForMember(member => member.LastName, viewModel => viewModel.Condition(source => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.LastName)));


    User user = new User 
    { 
        FirstName = "Jane", 
        LastName = "Doe", 
        UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() 
    };

    ChangeNameViewModel model = new ChangeNameViewModel 
    { 
        FirstName = "John" 
    };

    user = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ChangeNameViewModel, User>(model, user);

    Console.WriteLine ("First name:  {0}", user.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine ("Last name:   {0}", user.LastName);
    Console.WriteLine ("UserId: {0}", user.UserId);

    // Output should be:
    // ---------------------------
    // First name:  John
    // Last name:   Doe
    // UserId:      9fd25bfd-c978-4287-8d3d-890d67834c23
    // ---------------------------
}

public class User 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeNameViewModel 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, would it be possible to not map properties which are null?

Comment: I've modified the answer above... now, if your first name or last name is null or whitespace, it will ignore it.

Comment: If you've found this has answered your question, please mark it as the selected answer... thanks